# Custom fonts doesn't work in a certain html/css project

Tags: html, css, fonts

I can't change the fonts to custom fonts in my project. But The following code does work in a separate test case, but I don't know why this doesn't work in my working project. I don't know what is causing the issue.

- I can change the fonts to some default fonts but not custom fonts.

  ```css
  @font-face{
    font-family: nazanin;
    src: url(nazanin.ttf);
  }

  .customFont{
    font-family: nazanin;
  }
  ```

  ```html
  <h1 class="nazanin">This is a custom Font</h1>
  ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, is the path to your font really `nazanin.ttf`? Is it in the same folder as this current CSS file?

If it is in a separate folder called "fonts", then try something like this:

```css
@font-face{
  font-family: nazanin;
  src: url(../fonts/nazanin.ttf);
}
```

Second of all, the `.ttf` file extension is for Safari, iOS, and Android. Are you using a different browser? If so, that's the problem. I would suggest going with the `.woff` extension because it is compatible with most modern browsers.

Comment: Thank you! the issue was I forgot to include the double dots before the address.

Comment: You're welcome! If you would like your font to be available for more browsers, try an online WOFF converter.